# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python, list

Ok so I need to encrypt or decrypt a message given a list of integers, a message, and a keystream value. Whenever I run my function I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\v\Desktop\Assignment 1\cipher_functions.py", line 152, in <module>
result += decrypt_letter(i, get_next_keystream_value)
File "C:\Users\v\Desktop\Assignment 1\cipher_functions.py", line 51, in <module>
key_stream = (ord_char - key_value) builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'
```

These are the 2 functions which I believe are involved:

```
def encrypt_letter(my_char, key_value):
    '''(str, int) -> str
    '''
    my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
               'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
               'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    ord_char = (ord(my_char.upper()) - 65)
    key_stream = (ord_char + key_value)

    if key_stream > 25:
        result = (key_stream - 26)
    elif key_stream <= 25:
        result = key_stream

    key_streamed_value = my_list[result]

    return key_streamed_value

def decrypt_letter(my_upper_char, key_value):
    '''(str, int) -> str
    '''
    my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
               'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
               'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']    
    ord_char = (ord(my_upper_char) - 65)
    key_stream = (ord_char - key_value)

    if key_stream < 0:
        result = (key_stream + 26)
    elif key_stream >= 0:
        result = key_stream

    key_streamed_value = my_list[result]

    return key_streamed_value


def process_message(deck_cards, my_message, convert):
    '''(list of int, str, str) -> str
    '''
    result = ""
    new_message = clean_message(my_message)
    for i in new_message:
        if convert == 'e':
            result += encrypt_letter(i, get_next_keystream_value)
        elif convert == "d":
            result += decrypt_letter(i, get_next_keystream_value)
        return result
```

Does anyone know why this problem is occurring?

Comment: You're passing in `key_value` to `decrypt_letter` as a function. Did you forget to call it?

Comment: What is `get_next_keystream_value`.

Comment: it should probably be `get_next_keystream_value()` notice the parenthesis.

Comment: It wont work for either decrypt or encrypt says the same error

Comment: @vig143 What does `get_next_keystream_value` do? It is not mentioned anywhere else in your code

Comment: Check the type of variable `get_next_keystream_value` by `print type(get_next_keystream_value)`. It should be type `integer`.

Comment: Oh shoot I forgot to include the (deck_cards) and also another question. It works now but the result only has 1 letter value. Like when I do                                                                                      process_message([1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26], "Lake Hylia", "e")
it only outputs 'W' Where as the result should be 9 characters long. Why is the process message function only outputting a single character?

Comment: Ask a new question, the comment section isn't suitable for asking/presenting details.

Comment: The error message `key_stream = (ord_char - key_value) builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'` says that you are trying to subtract a function from an int.  The function in this case is `key_value`.  As @thebjorn says, you probably meant to call it before passing it to the function, but left off the parentheses.

Comment: bjorn thank you for your help. I just need help on the last question I answered on why its only outputting a single character. I'll post a new question next time, I'm new to stackoverflow so it'll take some time to learn the ways :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that `get_next_keystream_value` is not defined anywhere.

It is unclear if it is meant to be a variable which you have not initialized, or if it should be a function call for a function that has not been coded yet, in which case it should be `get_next_keystream_value()`.  Given the structure of your code, it looks like you are trying to pass it as the `key_value`, in which case you need to initialize it to an integer first.

Comment: dkhamrick I've fixed that problem I forgot to include(deck_cards) in the get_next_keystream_value(). But when  I do                  process_message([1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26], "Lake Hylia", "e") it only outputs 'W' Whereas the result should actually be 9 characters long. Why is the process message function only outputting a single character?

Comment: Where is the code for clean_message()?  It would help to see what that is returning.

Comment: def clean_message(my_string):
            '''(str) -> str
            Given a line of text, remove all non alphabetic characters and 
            change all the lowercase alphabetic characters to uppercase
            REQ: my_string must contain only one line of text
            >>> clean_message("g7*kG?4hdsjk9")
            'GKGHDSJK'
            '''
            this_string = ''
            alphabet =  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
            for i in my_string:
                if i in alphabet:
                    this_string += i
    
            return this_string.upper()

Comment: it basically just removes all non characters and capitalizes the letters

Comment: In the alphabet it also has upper case letters.

Comment: I cannot tell from your code, but is your return statement inside the for loop, by any chance?

Comment: It would really help if you could edit your original post with all of the necessary code so that we could look at it in its entirety.